# Python2 + SQLite not returning all rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write a Python (2) script that manages a SQLite3 database. I'm having trouble getting all of the rows from the table and looping through them. My table has 218 rows (according to PHP and sqlite3.exe) yet Python only loops through 8.

```
import sqlite3 as sql

db = sql.connect('database.db')
c = db.cursor()
n = 0

for row in c.execute('select * from table'):
    n += 1

print n
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some extra step that I need to take to get Python to loop through all of the rows?

Comment: Which eight records are looped through? (Print out some value in the loop.)

Comment: The records seem to be randomly selected from the database - they aren't alphabetical or in the order SELECT * FROM table results in in sqlite3.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like this:

```
conn     = sqlite3.connect(filename)
cursor   = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * from tablename')
results  = cursor.fetchall()
print '\nindividual records'
for result in results:
    print result
```